# Stack Overflow Password Recovery

Tags: support, login

When I send a forgotten password request, I see this:

[image: Account recovery email sent to redacted.]

When I check my e-mail, this is what I get:

[image: Someone requested an account recovery on Stack Overflow for redacted. If you didn't request this, just ignore this email. We'll keep your account safe. You can log in to Stack Overflow using the following credentials: redacted. Choose the "Log in with Stack Exchange option redacted. Reset your password if you've forgotten it.]

The site is giving me an infinite loop, the e-mail tells me to do what I've already done - fill out the forgotten password request.

How do I reset my password?

Comment: What mail client are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Clicking on "reset your password" **in the E-Mail** will redirect you to a page where you can set a new password.

Comment: I did that, it took me back to the place I started with no option to reset..

Comment: Okay, that's weird because I just tested it now a few times and it worked. The link should have a token to it like  `https://stackoverflow.com/account/recover?recoveryToken=iAdaVAA...`. Do you see that if you hover it? What mail program are you using?

Comment: It had a token, and I was using yahoo mail. It's okay, I can just stick to this account.

Comment: The same thing happened to me and I got the answer by reading this thread.  The wording of the email does not suggest that the `reset your password` link will lead you to a page that allows you to do so.